# IndexError: list index out of range with tkinter and procedures

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm recently adjusting to using `tkinter` alongside `Python` and as part of an assignment I've been asked to produce a tkinter-based program.
I decided I'd attempt a quiz which has three difficulties and is able to choose a question out of random from the list available for that difficulty.
When I run the program and select the difficulty (easy is all I've done up to now) it continues running but I get an error within the IDE:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:\Unit 6 - Software Development\randomtkintergame.py", line 98, in easy_mode
question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3 = easy[question_choice]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code I have:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from tkSimpleDialog import *
import math
import string
import time
from random import randint

global question_title, button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, question_number, score_count, easy, question_choice, question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3
question_number = 1
score_count = 0
question_choice = 0
question = 0
answer = 0
wrong_1 = 0
wrong_2 = 0
wrong_3 = 0

easy = [("What is the longest river in the world?", "The River Nile", "The Amazon River", "The River Humber", "The River Trent"),
    ("What is Doctor Who`s time box called?", "TARDIS", "TIMEY-WIMEY", "TASDIR", "WIMEY-TIMEY"),
    ("How many faces are on a die?", "6", "5", "7", "4"),
    ("How many wives did Henry VIII have?", "6", "8", "4", "9"),
    ("What is the square root of 169?", "13", "11", "17", "19"),
    ("In a game of chess, what is the only piece able to jump over other pieces?", "Knight", "Pawn", "Bishop", "All"),
    ("Who is the author of the `Harry Potter` books?", "J.K. Rowling", "J.R.R. Tolkien", "George R.R. Martin", "Julius Caesar"),
    ("What is the name of the clockwork device used by musicians to measure time?", "Metronome", "Tuner", "Amplifier", "Time Measurer"),
    ("Which two colours are Dennis the Menace`s jumper?", "Red and black", "Blue and black", "White and gold", "Red and blue"),
    ("An octagon has how many sides?", "8", "6", "10", "7"),
    ("Which sign of the zodiac is represented by the Ram?", "Aries", "Scorpio", "Ophiuchus", "Aquarius"),
    ("Which animal is associated with the beginning of an MGM film?", "A lion", "An alpaca", "A very small albatross", "A tiger"),
    ("What was the hunchback of Notre Dame`s name?", "Quasimodo", "Esmerelda", "Frollo", "Not Re Dame"),
    ("Who is the animated star of the computer game Tomb Raider?", "Lara Croft", "Sara Craft", "Tom Cruise", "Bill Gates"),
    ("What is the name of the city in which The Simpsons live?", "Springfield", "Quahog", "South Park", "Boston"),
    ("In which film would you first have come across the character of Marty McFly?", "Back to the Future", "Lord of the Rings", "The IT Crowd", "Harry Potter"),
    ("How many years are there in a millennium?", "1,000", "10,000", "100", "1,000,000"),
    ("In Greek mythology, what was Medusa`s hair made of?", "Snakes", "Threads of silk", "Stone", "Leeches"),
    ("What is the first letter of the Greek alphabet?", "A - Alpha", "B - Beta", "G - Gamma", "E - Epsilon"),
    ("What type of animal was Stuart, in the 1999 film `Stuart Little`?", "Mouse", "Frog", "Guinea pig", "Porcupine"),
    ("What creature appears on the flag of Wales?", "Dragon", "Alligator", "Crocodile", "Lizard"),
    ("On what part of the body would you wear a `sombrero`?", "Head", "Feet", "Hands", "Chest"),
    ("How many wheels are on a tricycle?", "3", "2", "6", "8"),
    ("Oxygen and which other element makes up water?", "Hydrogen", "Helium", "Ytterbium", "Einsteinium"),
    ("How many inches are in a yard?", "36", "12", "8", "24"),
    ("What colour is an emerald?", "Green", "Black", "Orange", "White")]


def easy_mode():
    global button_1, button_2, button_3, button_4, question_number, question_title, score_count, easy, question_choice, question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3
    repeat = True
    while repeat == True:
      for i in range (0, len(easy)): #the code works through all the questions
        question_choice = randint(0, 25)#generate random int
        question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3 = easy[question_choice]
        easy.pop(question_choice)

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("700x500")
root.title("Educational Quiz")
root.configure(background="#f2e5ff")


question_title = tk.Label(root, text="Please select a difficulty.", relief=GROOVE, bd=5, bg="#66b2ff", fg="black", font=("Calibri Light", 20))
question_title.place(x = 50, y = 25, width=625, height=80)




button_1 = tk.Button(root, text = "EASY", relief=GROOVE, bd=5, command = easy_mode, bg="#0055ff", fg="black", font=("Calibri Light", 20))
button_1.place (x = 50, y = 180 , width=300, height=80)
```

Of course, it's not the entire code as I didn't want to paste things that aren't actually related to the problem, but I can provide the rest if needed.
(Also, I might not need all the global variables set, but I'll deal with that when it's needed.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you continually select for the original range while shrinking the list, until you eventually get an index too large.  You could replace the while loop with

```
while easy:
    question_choice = randint(0, len(easy)-1)  #generate random int
    question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3 = easy[question_choice]
    easy.pop(question_choice)
```

but even better, I think, to present all questions in random order,

```
random.shuffle(easy)
for q_and_a in easy:
    question, answer, wrong_1, wrong_2, wrong_3 = q_and_a
```

Neither replacement is tested, so there may be a typo.

Comment: I used the first one, as it's the one I'm more familiar with. I see what the problem is now too, so thank you very much for the assistance!